# Session expires using state server on application pool refresh

Tags: session, pool, stateserver, recycle

I have a .NET 1.1 application hosted on two different servers, but on one of them whenever the application pool is recycled, all sessions are dropped.

Both applications are using “StateServer” session mode and as far as I could tell, both servers have exactly the same configuration and have the “ASP .NET State Server” service running.

This is a particularly troublesome issue, due to the fact that this application pool is recycling every 2-3 hours (that’s another issue that I have to solve).

Does anyone have any idea of might be causing this?

Thanks in advance,

Zeon

Answer (score 0):

Monitor the number of active user sessions in each State Server instance with the perfom counter "State Server Sessions Active" to (a) ensure that both servers are using STate Server and (b) see that this really is caused by the app pool recycling.

It's a bit umclear from your question if these two apps share session state, or if they are two different applications, that could be important for the solution.